# Convert Spring MVC to Spring fullREST JSON application

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I make application in Java Spring similar to:
[Java Blog Aggregator](https://github.com/jirkapinkas/java-blog-aggregator)

Author of this app use Spring MVC and common http request. Is it fast way to remodel of controllers to full rest application which use AJAX?
I do not know where to start.
I would like to send JSON. I don't have my own code now, cause I just getting started.

Example of controller:

```
package cz.jiripinkas.jba.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.ItemService;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("items", itemService.getItems());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, follow these steps:-

1. Download a JSON API jar and include that library in your application.
    You can download one [HERE](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/javax.json/javax.json-api-1.0.jar.zip)
2. Convert your `public String index(Model model)` method to 
   `public void index(Model model, HttpServletResponse response)`.
3. Remove the line `return "index";` as now your method is of `void` type.
4. Contruct a JSON  with the library you just added. You will finally have an object of type `JSONObject`
5. Once you have this object, convert and store into a String. For example, if you have a variable named `returnJSONObj` of type `JSONObject`, you can write convert it into a String as 
   `String returnJSONStr = returnJSONObj.toString()`
6. Finally, you have write the output at a JSON String:-
   `response.setContentType("application/json");
   response.getWriter.println(returnJSONStr);`

This will make your method return a JSON String, which you can use in your REST API.

## EDIT

Added sample code for reference

```
    package cz.jiripinkas.jba.controller;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    import cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.ItemService;

    @Controller
    public class IndexController {

        @Autowired
        private ItemService itemService;

        @RequestMapping("/index")
        public void index(Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {
            List items = itemService.getItems();
            String returnJSONStr =  createJSONStr(items);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.getWriter().println(returnJSONStr); //this method throws IOException
        }

        private String createJSONStr(List items) {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            for(Item item: items) { //For each item
                json.put("property1", item.getProperty1()); //replace by your own properties
                json.put("property2", item.getProperty2());
            }
            return json.toString();
        }


    }
```

Comment: thanks for your post. Can you attach example code for above controller that I better understand?

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a REST Webservice by :

1) Replacing @Controller with @RestController.

2) Changing @RequestMapping("/index") to :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index", 
method=RequestMethod.GET, 
produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

3) And if you intent to on receiving some payload in this index web service then replace `RequestMethod.GET` with `RequestMethod.POST` and change parameters of index function to some DTO object which will map with json you want to receive and annotate it with `@RequestBody`(This is optional in case you are using @RestController).

**EDIT :**

4) If you want to return a JSON object , you just need to create a bean with attribute names same as your keys :

```
class User {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
  }
  public void getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
  public void getId(){
    return this.id;
  }
  public void setId(String id){
    this.id=id;
  }
}
```

and return this object from the method as follows :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index", 
  method=RequestMethod.GET, 
  produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)    
public User index() {
  User user = new User();
  user.setId("1");
  user.setName("Test");
  return user;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to use this technique with Entity model variable which is in String index?

Comment: you mean how to return a json with some key value pairs from this method ?? am i right ?